# Do I have to retain a SEL

Tags: objective-c

When I get a selector passed to my method, should I just save it:

```
-(void) setCallBack:(SEL) selectorToCall
{
    self->mSelectorToCall = selectorToCall;
}
```

or should I retain?

```
-(void) setCallBack:(SEL) selectorToCall
{
    self->mSelectorToCall = [selectorToCall retain];
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the SEL type isn't an object reference, it's basically a constant string pointer. You can just assign it as in your first example.

Answer (score 5):

No, selectors are not objects, so you can't retain them.